# Django model update multiple instances with custom Manager function

Tags: django, django-models, sql-update, django-managers

I have a model class (for example `A`) inside the Django model framework. For this model I have created his Manager class with some functions.

```
class T_Manager(BaseModelManager):

    def add_function(value):
        ....

class T(BaseModel):
    objects = T_Manager()
    ....


class A(BaseModel):
    t = GenericRelation('T', related_name='t')
    ....
```

Now I have a list of `A` class objects and I would like to call `add_function` on all of them efficiently.

I would like to use something like

```
list_a.update(F('add_function', value))
```

or something like this.

Is there a way to call this function inside the update function or what is recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to call the `add_function()` method of `T_Manager` class inside `update()` method of `A` model.

To call `add_function()` on all `T` instances related to the `A` objects you can use loop to iterate through `T` objects:

```py
for a in list_a:
    for t in a.t.all():
        t.objects.add_function(value)
```

or use custom manager to iterate all related `T` objects:

```py
class A_Manager(BaseManager):
    def update_related_t(self, value):
        for a in list_a:
            for t in a.t.all():
                t.objects.add_function(value)
```

you can then call custom manager:

```py
A.objects.update_related_T(value)
```

Comment: Ok, I know for this method,... but this approach will hit the DB for every A object. If list_a is large it is a very ineffective way... is there a way to hit DB only once?